# When will Python garbage collect when passing an encoded str to ctypes library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I have a function in a library that expects a `char *`, to which I want to send an encoded `str`. I would ideally like to call `encode` inline to the function call:

```py
my_lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('my_lib.so')
my_string = 'hello'
my_lib.my_func(my_string.encode('utf-8'))
```

but I'm concerned that the `bytes` instance that's the return value of `my_string.encode('utf-8')` will get deleted (by garbage collecting or reference counting) by Python before the library function uses it. Is this possible, and so should I actually do the below?

```py
my_lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('my_lib.so')
my_string = 'hello'
my_string_encoded = my_string.encode('utf-8')
my_lib.my_func(my_string_encoded)
```

Comment: Which implementation?

Comment: @PeterWood Of Python? https://github.com/python/cpython (but happy for answers to cover different implementations)

Comment: Actually, it wouldn't make any sense for it to be garbage collected before `my_func` is called.

Comment: FWIW, garbage collector plays no role here at all: it is only the reference counting, that matters. When an object is passed as argument in a function, its ref-count is increased and thus its destruction is prevented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your code snippets are safe, because at the beginning of each fuction call, reference counters of arguments are incremented, and at return time they are decremented. Thus the temporary `bytes` object remains alive during the call, and its data pointer remains valid.